# What is the current main source of power in Futurama?

Tags: futurama

What kind of power do the people of Futurama use currently?

In the film *Bender's Game*, Farnsworth rendered all dark matter inert with his anti-backwards crystal. After that, he "invented" a new source of power (Nibbler Power). But in later episodes, cars and ships still fly.

What energy is being used to power these vehicles?

Comment: Continuity is not a common thing in Futurama.

Comment: @Paperjam While there are many absurdist throwaway jokes, continuity is a very common thing in Futurama.  See the setup of Fry's grand-parentage.

Comment: @Keen, if you ax me, even the absurdist jokes are part of the continuity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Whale Oil](http://theinfosphere.org/Whale_oil)

[image]

Leela and Fry get ready to top up.

Comment: This was actually set up in Season 3 "Bending in the Wind."  The Professor states that fossil fuel was used up, so now they use Whale Oil as an alternative for gasoline.

Answer (score 3):

After the collapse of Dark Matter, the crew turned to whale oil for fuel. It was revealed in 'Into the Wild Green Yonder' and has been used ever since.