# Whats the new fuel replacing dark matter?

Tags: futurama, robots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the current main source of power in Futurama?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18709/what-is-the-current-main-source-of-power-in-futurama)

So in benders game dark matter  becomes worthless and the professor use the niblonins(how ever it is spelled) to pull the ship but what do they use afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

After dark matter was worthless they used whale oil

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: http://theinfosphere.org/Whale_oil

Answer (score 0):

After dark matter became worthless they actually used Nibbler power.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?